# Regex for any character, minimum 5 length, [.] does not working

Tags: regex

Seems simple, but it drives me crazy: I'd like to have a check for a given string that can contain literally any character (regardless whether that is a number, letter, special char etc). The only criteria is to have at least 5 charachters in the string.

Tried:

```
/^[.]*{5,}$/

/^[.*]{5,}$/

/^.*{5,}$/

/^.{5,}$/
```

plus all the A-Za-Z0-9 etc stuff but to no avail.

Trying to use it in TS and C#.

Any idea please? Thank you

Comment: Do you have to use Regex?  Can you instead just do something like `input.length() > 5`?

Comment: must use regex , yes

Comment: you can go with `.{5,}`
https://regex101.com/r/9uwehh/1

Comment: tried that one (last example)

Comment: then it should work , you can test it out on the URL I posted

Comment: it seems it is not the syntax that causes issue then, but something else i need to figure. thank you

Comment: @Anurag, if this were [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) I'd suggest `.{5}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last one on your list is correct, `^.{5,}$` works as expected. [See it in action here.](https://regex101.com/r/VoRKma/1)

Comment: it seems it is not the syntax that causes issue then, but something else i need to figure. thank you

Answer (score 0):

rx engines start from begining.
this `.` matches anything if use dot-all modifier.

so when it tries to match 5 chars it either sucess or fail
right away. is no backtracking or anything else.

the fastest regex is this `.....` using //s dot-all modifier

no need for anchors `^$` for this and it doesnt mattir if more
than 5 engine ony care about minimum